# Why is the Mitchell order well-founded?

Tags: set-theory, filters, large-cardinals, well-orders

[Here](http://fa.its.tudelft.nl/~hart/onderwijs/set_theory/Jech/19-iterated_ultrapowers_and_LU.pdf), on page 358, I do not understand why 
we reach a contradiction once we show
$U_1>U_2>...>U_n>...$ is a **descending sequence in $M$?**
What does it contradict that this order holds in $M$?

Comment: Because these are measures on $\kappa $, and the least cardinal with such a decreasing sequence is $j(\kappa) $.

Answer (score 4):

We start with the *least* $\kappa$ on which the Mitchell order is ill-founded. Now pick a Mitchell-descending sequence $U_0>U_1>...$ of measures on $\kappa$. Let $j:V\rightarrow M$ be the elementary embedding associated to $U_0$. Since $j$ is elementary, we have that $M\models$"$j(\kappa)$ is the least cardinal where the Mitchell sequence is ill-founded."

Since $\kappa<j(\kappa)$, *this means that $M$ must not see the sequence $U_1>U_2>...$* - either because it doesn't contain $\{U_1, U_2, ...\}$ or because it doesn't believe $U_i>U_{i+1}$ for some $i$. So by showing that this sequence exists and is Mitchell-descending in $M$, we'll have a contradiction.

Since $U_i<U_0$ for $i>0$, we have $U_i\in M$ for all $i>0$. This means that the whole sequence is in $M$ (why?). So now *all we have to do is show $M\models U_i>U_{i+1}$ for $i>0$, and we'll be done. And this is what Jech does in the remainder of the proof.

Comment: So I do not know why: "This means that the whole sequence is in M". Can you help please?

Comment: And is $M$-ultrafilter $U_i$ on $\kappa$ **iterable** here for all $i$'s? How do we use/prove this fact?

Comment: And how do we see $P^M(\kappa)$=$P(\kappa)$ and $M^{\kappa}\subset M$?